# How to split a partition into two without formatting?

Tags: linux, partition, ssd

There is only one partition in my SSD currently. That is where the Linux code lies. I am using ubuntu distro.

```
$ lsblk -l /dev/sda
NAME MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda    8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk
sda1   8:1    0 298.1G  0 part /
```

Can I split this partition into two without formatting? If yes, how?

Comment: mandatory comment: be sure to backup your data **before**, then check restoration of some radom file/directory before proceeding.

Answer (score 4):

Can you? Sure.

Should you? **NO**

If you must extract and isolate additional storage from `sda` without the risk of data loss due to shrinking the primary drive which is never advised, then a safer approach would be to use `fallocate` to create a loop device.

`fallocate` is great for creating `swap` on systems but can also be used to great effect when partitioning is not an option.

First, create a mount point for the loop drive.

```
mkdir /NewDrive
```

Now, you can go ahead and create the loop device.

```
fallocate -l 5G NewStorage
```

The above command will create will create a file `NewStorage` with a file size of just under 5GB. You can confirm this with `ls -h`

Now that the storage is isolated rather than partitioned, you will need to create a filesystem with it.

```
mkfs.ext4 NewStorage
```

This will create a `ext4` filesystem. Now, you can mount it to the directory created earlier.

```
mount NewStorage /NewDrive
```

Your `lsblk` command should now return something like this

```
lsblk 
NAME MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda    8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk
sda1   8:1    0 298.1G  0 part /
loop0  7:0    0     5G  0 loop /NewDrive
```

And that is it without the risk of data loss or need for shrinking.

To see all active loop devices in use on your system, you can use `losetup`

```
losetup
NAME       SIZELIMIT OFFSET AUTOCLEAR RO BACK-FILE
/dev/loop0         0      0         1  0 /path/TO/NewDrive
```

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on `shrinking the filesystem is never advised`? (Even if it only an opinion it is useful for audience to know the reasons) +1 for  `fallocate`

Comment: @LutzWillek Thanks and apologies for any confusion, I was in a bit of a rush when I typed this up. I was refering to the storage drive. As there is only one in which the only partition is already allocated to `/`, shrinking of any kind would not be advisable though not impossible. It may be better and easier to just backup the system and rebuild with two partitions.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I have another system with two partitions:
              `lsblk /dev/sda
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2   8:2    0 465.3G  0 part /
`
 Is this scenario safer than the one above?

Comment: @HatLess Can I create an ocfs2 partition instead of ext4 with the same procedure?

Comment: @DivijaGogineni Sure you can, you can change to any filesystem you wish with the above. Regarding the second system, if there is not alot of data, then you can consider shrinking `sda2` and then use the available space to create `sda3`. There will still be the possibility of data loss, so if you must, I'd advise following LutzWillek answer.

Comment: @HatLess Thank you again. I tried creating ocfs2 fs but here's the error I get: mount.ocfs2: Cluster name is invalid while trying to join the group

Answer (score 2):

My guess: "without formatting" you meant "without loosing the data which are currently stored on my ssd". In case my guess is correct: yes, doing so is possible. You can repartition the current free space.

Before you start: Creating a whole disk or partition image backup is recommended before you resize or move a partition.

The steps (high level view) are:

- Shrink the filesystem on sda1 first.
- Shrink the partition sda1.
- Create new partitions.
- Create a new filesystem on the new partitions.

You can archive everything with command line tools, or by using graphical tools, as [gparted](https://gparted.org/).

The by far easiest way to archive your goal is to start a Linux live medium (means: do not start your linux from the SSD itself) and using a graphical tool.

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/89988 to learn how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can! Note that I'd suggest to backup any important data before doing that, just in case.

I used gparted gui tool, it allows you to shrink your partitions (yes, even if you are currently using them, e.g. your linux partition), you just shrink the needed partition with mouse and create a partition from an empty space.